# How to update value of input type=range

Tags: javascript, html

Why in my `playbackChange` function, the value doesn't update as expected?
https://jsfiddle.net/zestrdj7/.
I don't know if there's something wrong with *the way I update the `input[type="range"]`*, or anything with *float number/ value type*?

Reproduce the problem by **pressing `[` or `]`**, I expect the `playbackProgress.value` **decrement/increment by `0.1`** each press, but **it's stuck at 1.3/2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `playbackProgress.value` and `playbackProgress.step` are strings.

You can convert them into numbers using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Comment: Damn, thank you. I actually converted `step` to Number, but didn't realize that `value` has not.